# Swift . Share and save Pdf file

Tags: ios, swift, view, doc

Есть несколько pdf файлов. 
Я вывожу их название в таблице , а затем открываю в pdfView.

Файлы уже в самом приложении есть.

Как я могу скачать на сам телефон и поделиться этим файлом когда он открыт в pdfView. Я делаю это через UIBarButtonItem, но не могу написать  саму реализацию этих методов.

вот код pdfView

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

var nameFile:String?
var titleChapter:String?

class pdfView: UIViewController {

    // Share doc
    @IBAction func shareDocAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // path file
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: nameFile,  ofType:"pdf")

        // activity with file
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: PDFDocument.value(forKeyPath: path!) as! [Any] , applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //  Download file
    @IBAction func DownloadAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


        // how i can download ?

    }



    //Pdf view
    @IBOutlet var pdfDocView: PDFView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.title = titleChapter
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white

        //name Documents for view
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: nameFile,  ofType:"pdf") {
            if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path)) {
                pdfDocView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
                pdfDocView.autoScales = true
                pdfDocView.displayDirection = .vertical
                pdfDocView.document = pdfDocument
                 pdfDocView.canZoomIn()
                pdfDocView.canZoomOut()
                            }

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Через activityViewController Вы можете и сохранить и расшарить документ. Что именно не получается? Не работает activityViewController?

Comment: Да, не получаеться написать правильно реализацию  activityViewController

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Share doc
    @IBAction func shareDocAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // path file
        guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: nameFile, withExtension: "pdf"), let document = PDFDocument(url: path) else { return }

        // activity with file
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [document], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.title = titleChapter
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white

        let pdfView = PDFView()

        pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(pdfView)

        pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        if let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: nameFile, withExtension: "pdf"), let document = PDFDocument(url: path) {
            pdfView.document = document
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: activityViewController открывается, но там нету никаких приложений чтобы поделиться

Comment: Это может быть из за того что на телефоне старая ОС стоит ?

Answer (score 0):

Вот какой подход мне помог все реализовать.

```
 // Share doc
    @IBAction func shareDocAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: nameFile,  ofType:"pdf")
        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

        // Create the Array which includes the files you want to share
        var filesToShare = [Any]()

        // Add the path of the file to the Array
        filesToShare.append(fileURL)

        // Make the activityViewContoller which shows the share-view
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: filesToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

        // Show the share-view
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```